# Novel about a giant woman rampaging through a city, guy has to become a giant to stop her

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read about a novel a few years ago that I never got around to reading and I'm trying to find the title. Don't know the author.

It was about a guy's girlfriend or ex-girlfriend somehow turning into a giant and rampaging through a city, and the guy has to also become giant to stop her. Pretty sure the giant woman was called Ruth.

The cover of the book had some giant legs on it.

Note, it was not 'Fifty Feet of Trouble'.

Comment: Not [Swynmoor](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Swynmoor)? It has a woman becoming giant and rampaging through an army, but I can't find a detailed enough summary to know if the guy also becomes giant or not.

Answer (score 3):

*Enormity* (2012) by W. G. Marshall?

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13180573-enormity):

> *Enormity* is the strange tale of an American working in Korea, a lonely young man named Manny Lopes, who is not only physically small (in his own words, he's a “Creole shrimp”), but his work, his failed marriage, his race, all conspire to make him feel puny and insignificant-the proverbial ninety-eight-pound weakling.
>
> Then one day an accident happens, a quantum explosion, and suddenly Manny awakens to discover that he is big-really big. In fact, Manny is enormous, a mile-high colossus! Now there's no stopping him: he's a one-man weapon of mass destruction. Yet he means well.
>
> *Enormity* takes some odd turns, featuring characters like surfing gangbangers, elderly terrorists, and a North Korean assassin who thinks she's Dorothy from The Wizard of Oz. There's also sex, violence, and action galore, with the army throwing everything it has against the rampaging colossus that is Manny Lopes. But there's only one weapon that has any chance at all of stopping him: his wife.

The cover does have giant legs:

[image: giant legs over a city]

Chapter two is named "Manny and Ruth".

---

Found with the Google query `scifi book girlfriend giant rampage site:goodreads.com/book`.

Comment: These things happen in Korea all the time.

Comment: Wow, "quantum" really is the all-purpose magic word for the 21st century, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidW: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/pp

Comment: I dunno... this plot seems kind of like the opposite of what the Q is asking for. Seems like a weird detail to have remembered backwards.

Comment: @T.E.D. memory can be tricky, wouldn't be the first time on this site we'd have people remembering things upside down. We've even had folks convinced they watched a movie when they were actually reading a book... So it's worth a shot, especially when the rest (the cover, the name, the time period) matches so well ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah, I didn't vote down, for exactly that reason. I've seen questions here just like this where the OQ got one detail massively wrong. Still, this seems a bit much.

Comment: I think this might be it, the cover looks recognizable, except it's weird I remembered it back to front: I was so sure it was the husband having to stop the rampaging wife. I never read it though, so details have probably gotten mixed up since I heard of it a few years ago. Thanks -- I want to check it as the right answer but the check mark isn't appearing for me.